# How to get Vue in vue3 which is undefined in other files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Hi i have a situation something like this

I have 2 files

1. main.js
2. utils.js

**main.js**

```
 import { createApp } from 'vue'
 import Utils from "./utils.js"
 import router from "...."
 import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'

 const app = createApp(App);
          app.use(router);
          app.use(VueCookies)
          app.use(Toast,Utils.toastConfig())
          app.mount('#app')
```

**utils.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default{
   setCookie(params){
      Vue.$cookies.set(params.name, params.value)
   }
  ...  
  // so on related to Vue.$cookies
}
```

**Note:** above file usage is in multiple places, changing everywhere is not feasible now as we are migrated from vue2 to vue3

**Question:** `Vue` is undefined in `utils.js` how to make it work without much code changes

Comment: Have you tried with deconstructing `import {Vue} from "vue"`?

Comment: There is a package called `@vue/compat` that you might want to check.